# How do I override PrestaShop's products class to limit the number of products returned in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, product, prestashop

line 2070 there is an SQL like this :

```
SELECT product_shop.id_product, product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
'.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
LEFT JOIN  `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa ON (product_shop.id_product = pa.id_product)
'.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa', false, 'product_attribute_shop.default_on = 1').'
WHERE product_shop.`active` = 1
'.(($ids_product) ? $ids_product : '').'
AND p.`id_product` IN (
    SELECT cp.`id_product`
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON (cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`)
    WHERE cg.`id_group` '.$sql_groups.'
)
'.($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '').'
AND (pa.id_product_attribute IS NULL OR product_attribute_shop.default_on = 1)
GROUP BY product_shop.id_product
ORDER BY RAND()
```

I want to know if I can Delete :

```
'.(($ids_product) ? $ids_product : '').'
```

Because with 16k products, I have 16k "OR" and it's too big and it takes too much ressource from my server.

I Added a "LIMIT 0, 200" too and I don't know if it's good ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `limit` should work. Your other changes may produce the desired results as well.

The most important thing is that you do not alter the core files as this could lead to unanticipated changes to other parts of your site.

Prestashop provides a way for you to override the core files without breaking everything and will allow you to quickly revert back to the original.

Copy the file `products.php` to the `overrides` directory and make your changes there.

You can find support and documentation for Prestashop overrides @ [Overriding default behaviors](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors?desktop=true)

Comment: Thank you for the answer !
I didn't know for the overrides, good advice !

Do you know what is the real function for this classes ? because it's write "Get a random special" but why this function is called on each page ?

Comment: The `products class` is the `base class` for products that all of the modules, components, plugins, etc use to extend PrestaShop's functionality. If `get a random special` is calling on every page, it is likely because a module is implementing that. Check in your Admin area for the `Specials Block`.

Comment: Hoooo God ! Thanks !
I found the module called "promotion" who was called on each header. I  disabled it and I didn't need to change the code now.